# How do I find missing EXE output of IExpress?

Tags: iexpress

I recently ran IExpress and set the output location to my desktop. It appeared to finish successfully, but when I went to the desktop to find my executable file, it wasn't there. The DDF and SED are, though. Any idea what's going on and how to solve it?

Comment: iexpress should delete the `.ddf` file if all went well. What happens when you run `makecab /f C:\path\to\file.ddf` ? That might generate some more informative error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It compressed the 20 files (originally ~8.8 MB) down to ~3.7 MB. What sort of thing were you expecting?

Comment: Since the `.ddf` file is normally deleted on success, I was wondering if the `makecab` operation was failing. I was hoping that running it manually might reveal some error. Based on your reply, I’m guessing it didn’t give an error, and thus we’re back to square one. If this were me, I’d get Process Monitor out and see what `iexpress.exe` was doing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question with a workaround answer: don't use IExpress. Try Inno Setup instead. The website was down for a few days, so I had been unable to download it.

I'm still running into issues with the output that's being produced, but the problem seems to have originated in a previous step (specifically, while using PyInstaller to freeze my code).

Anyhow, Inno Setup is the bees' knees. Thanks for the attempt, fission.